# How to pass $GET parameters to PHP function to update PostgreSQL table successfully?

Tags: javascript, php

I've been trying to resolve this problem for the past 2 days and have searched through every single remotely similar question here on SO but nothing seems to work.

What I am trying to achieve: Through a button click on index.php to trigger process.php with JS, which in turn updates the value in the selected row in the table in the Postgresql DB.

My function which is triggered by a button click;

```
function myFunction(name, status)
{
        var request = $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { n : name, s : status }
        }   
    });
}
```

process.php

```
$query="update guests set status=\$1 where name=\$2";
$params=array(strval($status), strval($name));
$result = pg_query_params($conn, 'update guests set status=$1 where name=$2', $params);
```

The string values of 'n' and 's' are passed over to `process.php` and I have verified they are being passed over correctly.

However, I am unable to get the `update` statement to execute successfully via the button click. Visiting `process.php` works perfectly and if I replace the query with one without variables, the button click worked perfectly as well.

So I am certain that the problem must be due to the variables not being 'recognised'? Outputting the query to console.log appears to be correct and I even verified the parameters data type (string).

What am I missing out? Really appreciate any help and please let me know if you require any clarification on my question. Thank you.

**Edit**

*In reply to "Howo do you get the value in your php file?":*

```
$name = $_GET["n"];
$status = $_GET["s"];
```

After getting the values, I do a simple `if` check and run the `update` SQL command with the variables.

*In reply to "How do you define $1 and $2":*

They are defined in 'pg_query_params' and takes the value from $params.

**Edit 2**

The button to trigger the function:

```
<button onclick=myFunction($name,$status)>Update</button>
```

$name, $status defined in the corresponding row in the table to the button.

**Edit 3**

`index.php`: https://hastebin.com/raw/yuxokepujo

`process.php`: https://hastebin.com/raw/ebuyusadep

Database is just 1 table with 3 columns: name, hereornot, banquet_table (changed from status but was not the issue as the problem still persists).

**Edit 4**

I'd like to re-emphasize that `process.php` runs without any issue when it is executed directly and the `update` query works without issue if I replace the variables with actual values.

**Edit 5**

*In reply to "Please show me the data received from the GETs":*

The following code:

```
$name = $_GET["n"];
$status = $_GET["s"];

echo('======START GET values======');
echo($name);
echo('============');
echo($status);
echo('======END GET values======');
```

...yields the following output:

> ======START GET values======John Doe============0======END GET values======

**Final Edit**

Unfortunately, no one was able to resolve this issue even with the code provided. I went with another more straightforward method in the end to implement what I needed

Comment: Howo do you get the value in your php file?

Comment: How do you define `$1` and `$2`

Comment: I've updated my question in response to your comments @Sfili_81

Comment: if you `var_dump($_GET)` what do you get?

Comment: @DevDonkey I'm not sure if I understood your question, but the function `process.php` does not return anything and its only purpose is to `update` the particular row value in the Postgresql table. Which variable should I  `var_dump` to give you more insight into my question?

Comment: Do you get some error in your console browser? Write a success and error function for your ajax call so you can know what happens. P.S. you have an extra  bracket '}'  in your js code

Comment: @Sfili_81 no errors, I did a check with console.log and the function runs successfully without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is
`'update guests set status=$1 where name=$2'`
While if I'm correct `status` is reserved keyword, that is why your query doesn't work.

Change is to and try again

```
update `guests` set `status`=$1 where `name`=$2'`
```

And remember to escape your variables as well as tables and column names in queries.

Comment: I've renamed the column but problem still persists. I appreciate the suggestion though. It was a good one and unfortunately not the issue at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Where are `$name` and `$status` coming from in your html? Are they PHP vars? If so you need to do

```
<button onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $name; ?>','<?php echo $status; ?>')">Update</button>
```

Note the double quotes surrounding your onclick function and single quotes around each parameter.

If it's `$name/state` are NOT PHP, please add more code and we'll figure it out.

Edit:
Replace

```
$name = json_encode(trim($line["name"]));
$hereornot = json_encode(trim($line["hereornot"]));

$name = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $name);
$hereornot = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $hereornot);  

echo("<tr>");
echo("<td>" . $name . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $hereornot . "</td>");
echo("<td><button onclick=myFunction($name,$hereornot)>Update</button></td>");
```

With:

```
$name = trim($line["name"]);
$hereornot = trim($line["hereornot"]); 

echo("<tr>");
echo("<td>" . str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $name) . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $hereornot) . "</td>");
echo("<td><button onclick=myFunction('$name','$hereornot')>Update</button></td>");
```

Comment: I've added complete code to the main post (Edit 3). Thank you. :)

Comment: Please do a view source on the process.php page and paste the button html.

Comment: <button onclick="myFunction(&quot;John&nbsp;Doe&quot;,&quot;0&quot;)">Update</button>

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Replaced the snippet with your code and index.php unable to load (Error 500). Data was manually inserted into the database and it was a bit funky which was why I added the `json_encode`. Now removing `json_encode` triggers the error 500.

Comment: Did not fix the issue, same behaviour as `json_encode`

Comment: Updated post. Please see `Edit 5`.

Comment: Button works and even returns the 'successful' message from `process.php` but the sql statement `update` doesn't go through. It only goes through if visit `process.php` directly or modify the `update` sql statement to exclude the variables.

So it's very strange and I am certain the problem lies with how I'm handling the passing of the variables from `index.php` to `process.php` since the code does work by itself.

Comment: Try change the elseif to else for the $status

Comment: No effect. It was _if_ previously but I changed it to _elseif_ to try.

Comment: Need to check your db connection then. Try echo "update guests set hereornot='$status' where name='$name'"; See if that query works

Comment: The output: `update guests set hereornot='1' where name='John Doe'` that's what you're asking for right? The `$name` and inverse of `$status` essentially being values in the GET url.

Comment: Is that valid against your DB?

Comment: Yes. The command is valid in my db when executing process.php directly.